# Generating Manipulate 'sliders' on the fly

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica's Manipulate function takes as its final arguments separate lists of the parameters you want sliders for along with their value ranges. But why not a list of lists?
This way I could I easily generate all the sliders for this big list of transformation rules that I have, e.g.:

```
parms = {a -> 2, b -> 4, c -> 5};
Table[{{parms[[i]][[1]], parms[[i]][[2]]}, 0, 10}, {i, 1,Length[parms]}]

{{{a, 2}, 0, 10}, {{b, 4}, 0, 10}, {{c, 5}, 0, 10}}
```

What I would like to have, however, is:

```
{{a, 2}, 0, 10}, {{b, 4}, 0, 10}, {{c, 5}, 0, 10}
```

This I'm copy pasting now between cells, which is rather messy. I'm sure there's a better way to do this. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Please see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4108/125) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1200/125) on similar questions.

What you need is `Sequence@@` to get the list of lists to be treated as your desired output when used as input.

Perhaps something like:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c];
parms = {a -> 2, b -> 4, c -> 5}; 
With[{values = Table[parms[[i]][[1]], {i, 1, Length[parms]}],
controls = Sequence @@
 Table[{{parms[[i]][[1]], parms[[i]][[2]], 
   Style[ToString[parms[[i]][[1]]], Red, Bold]}, 0, 10}, {i, 1, 
  Length[parms]}]},
Manipulate[values, controls]]
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is exactly the type of generic solution I was hoping I'd get.

Comment: @Big_bodySmall_heart, glad to be of help.